# How to unlock Google safe search

Tags: google-search

I am using windows 10.  I don't have (or want) a google account, but I use google as my search engine.  I am unable to unlock the safe search filter.  Must I have a google account to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you're on the Google home page, you should be able to reach the settings page and disable SafeSearch even without being logged in. Here's a couple screenshots in case you can't find it. The first setting on the page is SafeSearch.

[image: Screenshot of Google homepage]
[image: SafeSearch setting location]

Answer (score 0):

Instructions to Lock or Unlock safesearch are [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/510?hl=en)

> **Lock or unlock SafeSearch**
>
> Visit the Search Settings page. To turn on
> SafeSearch, check the box next to "Filter explicit results." To lock
> SafeSearch, click the Lock SafeSearch link next to "Filter explicit
> results." At this point, you may be prompted to sign in. Once you're
> signed in, confirm that you want lock SafeSearch by clicking Lock
> SafeSearch. You'll see a confirmation page once the lock is on. To
> unlock SafeSearch, follow the same instructions and click Unlock
> SafeSearch instead of Lock SafeSearch.
>
> **Lock SafeSearch on multiple browsers & devices**
>
> If you have more than
> one browser on your computer or tablet, you need to set the lock on
> each browser on your computer or tablet. If your computer or tablet
> has more than one user profile, you need to set the lock on each
> profile. The SafeSearch lock only works if your browser allows
> cookies.
>
> **Tips for locking SafeSearch for network administrators**
>
> If you
> deploy a proxy on your web traffic, it may be possible to configure
> your proxy to append &safe=strict to all search requests sent to
> Google. This parameter enables strict SafeSearch for all searches,
> regardless of the setting on the Google Preferences page.
>
> This technique will not work on searches done using SSL Search. Learn
> more about SSL Search

By default, I believe safe search is disabled. If it's locked in your browser, you should see this:

[image: Locked safesearch]

If you do, either someone has logged in and locked it, or you have a proxy enforcing it. Try using another browser and see if it's locked there, and checking your proxy settings to see if it is set. If so, it may be adding `&safe=strict` to your searches.